# c# como usar o metodo POST com o Restsharp

Tags: c#, json

Eu tenho um código para fazer um login, mas que quando mando os dados corretos o API continua a mandar o código "Unauthorized".

O código é o seguinte:

```
var client = new RestClient("link");
var request = new RestRequest("/v1.5/auth/authenticate", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
string user = "{\"nif\":\"15551\", \"nome\":\"teste\", \"password\":\"teste2\", \"loja\": 17 }";
request.AddParameter("text/json", user, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Dando uma olhada na documentação do Restsharp, você não deveria usar o metódo AddBody() para adicionar seu json? Esse AddParameter está meio estranho com esse "text/json".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O meu problema era nao ter o "user" antes do inicio do código JSON e no ADDParameter estava errado.

```
var client = new RestClient("link");
var request = new RestRequest("/v1.5/auth/authenticate", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
string user = "{\"user\":{\"nif\":\"15551\", \"nome\":\"teste\", \"password\":\"teste2\", \"loja\": 17 }}";
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", user, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```